# How to get all possible combinations from hash's values

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have a hash of arrays like this:

```
{a: [1, 2], b: [3, 4]}
```

I'm trying to build an array with all possible combinations of values, each from different key-value pairs, in the following form:

```
[{a: 1, b: 3}, {a: 1, b: 4}, {a: 2, b: 3}, {a: 2, b: 4}]
```

The hash can have `n` keys and each can have `m` values - I cannot assume any number. Each value (array) can have different size. The following is also a valid input:

```
{a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5, 6, 7], c: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]}
```

The best I got is an array with all value permutations but without the keys:

```
a = {a:[1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5, 6], c: [7, 8, 9]}
a.reduce([]) { |acc, (k, v)| acc.empty? ? v : acc.product(v)  }.map(&:flatten)
=> [[1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 8], [1, 4, 9], [1, 5, 7], [1, 5, 8], [1, 5, 9], [1, 6, 7], [1, 6, 8], [1, 6, 9], [2, 4, 7], [2, 4, 8], [2, 4, 9], [2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 8], [2, 5, 9], [2, 6, 7], [2, 6, 8], [2, 6, 9], [3, 4, 7], [3, 4, 8], [3, 4, 9], [3, 5, 7], [3, 5, 8], [3, 5, 9], [3, 6, 7], [3, 6, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

How should I do this in Ruby?

Comment: The length of array for every key is same?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon No, it can vary.

Comment: If `h` is your hash this question is about the array `h.values`. That is, the question is really about arrays, however they are obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Plan:

Start with an array that contains an empty hash.

each key-value pair:  map each hash in array to an array of `hash.merge({key=> value})` for each value.  Flatten

Repeat for each key

```
hash = {a: [1, 2], b: [3, 4]}
array = [{}]
hash.each_pair do |key, values|
  array.map! do |hash| 
    values.map do |value|
      hash.merge({key=> value})
    end
  end.flatten!
end

array
=> [{:a=>1, :b=>3}, {:a=>1, :b=>4}, {:a=>2, :b=>3}, {:a=>2, :b=>4}]
```

Could be cleaned up with nicer code and usage of enumerable methods, but that should be your general idea.

Comment: Thanks! One syntax error: it should be `hash.merge({key => value})`.

Comment: Oh yeah, when I ran it I ran into that problem, but I guess I pasted old code.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = { a: [1, 2], b: [3, 4], c: [5, 6] }
values = a.values
values.first.product(*values[1..-1]).map { |e| a.keys.zip(e).to_h }
#=> [{:a=>1, :b=>3, :c=>5}, {:a=>1, :b=>3, :c=>6}, 
#    {:a=>1, :b=>4, :c=>5}, {:a=>1, :b=>4, :c=>6}, 
#    {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>5}, {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>6}, 
#    {:a=>2, :b=>4, :c=>5}, {:a=>2, :b=>4, :c=>6}]
```

Works with a hash with any keys count.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on `n`, `m` values. If these constants has **small** values - you can make, store and use actual combinations. It is not possible to do it when these constants has **large** values.

Please try [OCG](https://github.com/andrew-aladev/ocg) options combination generator. It won't store any combination, it works as unidirectional iterator. It can handle billions of different combinations.

```rb
require "ocg"

generator = OCG.new(
  a: 1..3,
  b: 4..7,
  c: 8..12
)

puts generator.next until generator.finished?
```

Generator includes much more functionality that will help you to deal with other options.